# Why is zero and alphabet missing when I display the variable in PHP?

Tags: php, string, variables

I'm new to PHP and I got somebody else's code to work on.

There are multiple variables including $CARD.

But unlike other variables $CARD cannot display a character.

For example, when I input a value like 'passw0rd', all the other variables outputs 'passw0rd'. But the $CARD variable outputs a '0'.

And also, when I take an input like '0123', all the other variables outputs the same '0123'. But only the $CARD variable drops the 0 and outputs '123'.

Is there any PHP elements that I should be suspecting/?

Comment: Check the type of `$CARD` sounds like it's being cast to an integer.

Comment: any code to share?

Comment: Share your code if possible because $CARD works fine for me.

Comment: you can use var_dump($card) and check it's type.

Comment: The type of the variable is a string. And it's difficult for me to share the code because the code belongs to the client's company..

Answer (score 0):

If you see some thing like this in the code. that $CARD variable is cast to int.

```
$num = "3.14";
$CARD = (int)$num;
```

You can convert it to string as follows.

```
$var2 = (string)$CARD;
```